# np.where condition first instance ok, second instance throws error

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe where with a date column containing dates with both day-first('european') and month-first(american) dates. I have a separate column of type int containing 'year' values. The date strings of df.year<2017 are month-first and those from df.year>2017 are day-first.

I am using a np.where condition to separate the month and day from the date strings into separate columns to build a datetime thereafter. So I have this data:

```
'year' 'number' 'date'
2016    75  01/05/2017 00:00
2016    75  01/06/2017 00:00
2016    75  01/06/2017 00:00
2016    75  01/06/2017 00:00
2016    75  01/06/2017 00:00
2016    75  01/09/2017 00:00
2016    75  01/09/2017 00:00
2016    75  01/10/2017 00:00
2016    75  01/10/2017 00:00
2017    0   01/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   01/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   01/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   01/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   02/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   03/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   04/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   04/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   04/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   04/01/2017 00:00
2017    0   05/01/2017 00:00
```

I have already used this to create the month values:

```
df['dt_mo'] = np.where(df.year<2017,df.date.str.extract(r'(\d+)\/\d+\/\d+'), df.date.str.extract(r'\d+\/(\d+)\/\d+'))
```

This works fine to remove the month. I had tried other methods as well but since ['year'] is type(int) this is working fine

However, when I try to do a similar process to extract the day value it throws an error.

I have tried flipping the greater/less than operator and also by swapping the capture groups.

```
(1)sl['dt_dy'] = np.where(sl.year>2017, sl.date.str.extract(r'(\d+)\/\d+\/\d+'),sl.date.str.extract(r'\d+\/(\d+)\/\d+'))
```

or

```
(2)df['dt_dy'] = np.where(df.year<2017,df.date.str.extract(r'\d+\/(\d+)\/\d+'), df.date.str.extract(r'(\d+)\/\d+\/\d+'))
```

Both return the following common error, "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1".

Ideally the df.dt_dy would return the day digit value in the same way as the df.dt_mo currently returns the month digit value.

As always would greater appreciate any cleaner approaches

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you ultimately want to make the `datetime`, so create it from the start with `np.where` specifying the different formats. If you need the days you can now use the `datetime` accessors.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['my_date'] = np.where(df.year < 2017, 
                         pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce'),
                         pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce'))
```

---

```
    year  number              date    my_date
0   2016      75  01/05/2017 00:00 2017-01-05
1   2016      75  01/06/2017 00:00 2017-01-06
2   2016      75  01/06/2017 00:00 2017-01-06
3   2016      75  01/06/2017 00:00 2017-01-06
4   2016      75  01/06/2017 00:00 2017-01-06
5   2016      75  01/09/2017 00:00 2017-01-09
6   2016      75  01/09/2017 00:00 2017-01-09
7   2016      75  01/10/2017 00:00 2017-01-10
8   2016      75  01/10/2017 00:00 2017-01-10
9   2017       0  01/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-01
10  2017       0  01/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-01
11  2017       0  01/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-01
12  2017       0  01/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-01
13  2017       0  02/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-02
14  2017       0  03/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-03
15  2017       0  04/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-04
16  2017       0  04/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-04
17  2017       0  04/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-04
18  2017       0  04/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-04
19  2017       0  05/01/2017 00:00 2017-01-05
```

Comment: Awesome! I also have 2 further columns with sporadic start and end times. Can I add these one or both of these times to the respective datetimes after they have already been created?

Comment: @jrbwt yeah definitely. As long as your convert them to `timedelta` or `datetime` then you should be able to add them.